# Issue with jdbc connector to Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, azure-databricks

I've used the below query to fetch data from Oracle 11g and 12c into a dataframe and this works perfectly. However, when I try connecting to on-premise Oracle 9i, this is giving me empty rows though there is data in it.
Any pointers on how to resolve this ?

```
vDriver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
vURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname:portnumber/SID>"  

vUser = "xxxx"
vPassword = "xxxx"
pTableName = "xxxx"

df_Oracle = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
.option("driver", vDriver)\
.option("url", vURL)\
.option("dbtable", pTableName)\
.option("user", vUser)\
.option("oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion", "false")\
.option("password", vPassword)\
.load()

df_Oracle.show()
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the query is executing successfully and simply not returning any rows? Are you sure there are no errors occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to check is which JDBC driver do you  use.
This is basically the jar `ojdbcNN.jar` you have on the CLASSPATH, e.g. `ojdbc7.jar`

Typically you check the Oracle JDBC compatibility matrix in [What is the JDBC and RDBMS interoperability matrix or the certification matrix?](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html)

This will not help you for Oracle 9, as the oldest version mentioned there (as supported) is  11.2.0.4.

Anyway you may try to use some older version of the JDBC driver, that was distributed with Oracle 9 - possible the `classes12.jar`. Check [older Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b10979/getsta.htm) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marmite Bomber. First of all I've had issues finding the classes12.jar. Tried loading directly from Maven but it was failing to install. I then found classes12.jar file to download and uploaded it manually. That did the trick. Really helpful and a great help. Thanks